# Fatal error: Call to private MyObject::__construct() from invalid context

Tags: php

When creating a new object in PHP, I get the following error message:
`Fatal error: Call to private MyObject::__construct() from invalid context`
I just create the new object and do not try to call the constructor explicitly.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: creating a new object will always call the constructor.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your `MyObject` class has a protected or private constructor, which means that the class cannot be instantiated.  `__construct()` functions are always called when an object is instantiated, so trying to do something like `$x = new MyObject()` will cause a fatal error with a private construction function.  (If you do not specifically declare a `__construct()` function, the parent constructor will be called).

Private constructors are often used in Singleton classes to prevent direct instantiation of an object.  If it's not a class that you built, it might have a `getInstance()` function available (or something similar) to return an instance of itself.

Comment: That worked, I think I've seen people declaring private constructors before.  Is there any reason to do this?

Comment: The only reason to do it is if you don't wish the class to be instantiated for some reason.  As I mentioned in the answer, the Singleton pattern is a popular reason you might do this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Private constructors are often used by PHP implementations of the Singleton pattern, and are sometimes used with Factories.  For example, a factory static method of the class can search for locally cached instances of objects and return a reference instead of a new object.  Making the constructor private will prevent any accidental bypasses of the factory method.

Comment: So, What is the solution?

Comment: Singleton is not the only reason to have a private constructor. Sometimes it is nice to be able to disable the constructor by making it private and create one or more *named constructors* which you do by creating a public static method which intializes an instance and returns it

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$x = new MyObject()` you could use

```
$x = MyObject::getInstance();
```

assuming that `MyObject` is a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Implementation) and `getInstance()` function is available.

Answer (score 3):

For me its was that the name of the **CLASS** was the same name as one of the **method**s
that was private...

for example...

```
class myClass {

   public function __construct() {

   }

   private function myClass() {

   }
}
```