# private function __construct() not working when class called on another page

Tags: php, class, oop

im using the following type of class...

```
class datas{


    protected $req ;
    protected $db ;


    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
        $this->db->connect(); 
    }

    public function prnt()
    {
       echo "afafa6e5f1ga56d18a1ge";
    }
}
```

when i try and access the class like

```
$y = new datas();
$y->prnt();
```

> Call to protected data::__construct() from invalid context

when i turn it to public, it works. is there any way to make the constructor private and still have the method of call like i have. and i was thinking which one is more secure .

any insight is appreciated guys.

Comment: A class with private or protected cannot be instantiated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997721/fatal-error-call-to-private-myobject-construct-from-invalid-context.

Comment: note there is a discrepancy between the class name and visibility in the class and in the error message (data vs datas, protected vs private). In any case, a non-public ctor obeys the same rules as any other non-public method in terms of where it can be called.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor should be public because it's being called outside of the class context.

PHP may hide that for you, with `new`, but that's still what's happening.

Comment: is there a way to call it inside the class context ?

Comment: You could create a static public member function on the class, and have it `return new datas();`. Instead of using `new` to create a new instance outside the class, you'd use `$x = datas::MyStaticFunction();`

Comment: yeah, but why? I mean, if the OP can change the class, then s/he can just as well change the ctor back to public.

Comment: I'm not here to ask why; I'm just answering their questions. But this would just be a Factory pattern. There could be any number of reasons to do this, and some of them are actually legitimate. In a real world example, maybe datas is an abstract base class and `datas::MyStaticFunction()` will return a different subclass of datas depending on which database the user configured for the app.

Answer (score -1):

```
$y = new data();
```

should be

```
$y = new datas();
```

Comment: yea ok...that was just a typo..thanks...

Comment: could the issue be in Database class constructor ? if I comment out the DB connection part (since I don't have code for that class), your code seems to be working.

Comment: nah changed it....it should have been  private function __construct()

Comment: why do you want a private constructor ?

Comment: given that the ctor holds a Database class my assumption is that this is an attempt at creating a [Singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323).

Comment: that makes sense. I think this answer also addresses something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079/in-a-php5-class-when-does-a-private-constructor-get-called